# Hive HBase Integration behavior in the event of a failure

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hbase

I recently did an integration between Hive and HBase. I created a hive table with HBase serde and when i insert the records into the hive table it gets loaded into the HBase table. I am trying to understand what if the insert into HiveHBase table fails in between ? (HBase service fails / network issue). I assume the records which have already loaded into the HBase will be there and when i do a rerun of the operation i will have two copies of data with different timestamp (Assuming out of 20K records 10k was inserted and the failure occured).

1. What is the best way to insert records into HBase ?
2. Can Hive provide me the security check to see if the data is already there ?
3. Is mapreduce the best shot for scenarios like these ? I will write a mapreduce program that reads data from hive and checks record by record in hbase before the insertion . This makes sure there are no duplicate writes

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have 2 versions of data when you rerun the load operation. But that's ok since the 2nd version will get cleaned up on the next compaction. As long as your inserts are idempotent (which they most likely are), you won't have a problem.

At Lithium+Klout, we use a custom built HBaseSerDe which writes HFiles, instead of using Put's to insert the data. So we generate the HFiles and use the bulk load tool to load all of the data after the job has completed. That's another way you can integrate Hive and HBase.